# Python - Speed up for converting a categorical variable to it's numerical index

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert a column of categorical variables in a Pandas data frame into a numerical value that corresponds to the index into an array of the unique categorical variables in the column (long story !) and here's a code snippet that accomplishes that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col': ["baked","beans","baked","baked","beans"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
uniq_lab = np.unique(df['col'])

for lab in uniq_lab:
    df['col'].replace(lab,np.where(uniq_lab == lab)[0][0].astype(float),inplace=True)
```

which converts the data frame:

```
    col
 0  baked
 1  beans
 2  baked
 3  baked
 4  beans
```

into the data frame:

```
    col
 0  0.0
 1  1.0
 2  0.0
 3  0.0
 4  1.0
```

as desired. But my problem is that my dumb little for loop (the only way I've thought of to do this) is slow as molasses when I try to run similar code on big data files. I was just curious as to whether anyone had any thoughts on whether there were any ways to do this more efficiently. Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['col'] = pd.factorize(df.col)[0]
print (df)
   col
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    1
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#factorizing-values)

EDIT:

As [`Jeff`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672704/python-speed-up-for-converting-a-categorical-variable-to-its-numerical-index/37672792#comment62831903_37672792) mentioned in comment, then the best is convert column to `categorical` mainly because less [memory usage](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#memory-usage):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype("category")
```

**Timings**:

It is interesting, in large df `pandas` is faster as `numpy`. I cant believe it.

`len(df)=500k`:

```
In [29]: %timeit (a(df1))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.27 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit (a1(df2))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.32 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit (b(df3))
10 loops, best of 3: 24.6 ms per loop

In [32]: %timeit (b1(df4))
10 loops, best of 3: 24.6 ms per loop
```

`len(df)=5k`:

```
In [38]: %timeit (a(df1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 274 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit (a1(df2))
The slowest run took 6.71 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 273 µs per loop

In [40]: %timeit (b(df3))
The slowest run took 5.15 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 295 µs per loop

In [41]: %timeit (b1(df4))
1000 loops, best of 3: 294 µs per loop
```

`len(df)=5`:

```
In [46]: %timeit (a(df1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 206 µs per loop

In [47]: %timeit (a1(df2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 204 µs per loop

In [48]: %timeit (b(df3))
The slowest run took 6.30 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 164 µs per loop

In [49]: %timeit (b1(df4))
The slowest run took 6.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 164 µs per loop
```

**Code for testing**:

```
d = {'col': ["baked","beans","baked","baked","beans"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print (df)
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
#test for 5k
#df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)


df1,df2,df3, df4 = df.copy(),df.copy(),df.copy(),df.copy()

def a(df):
    df['col'] = pd.factorize(df.col)[0]
    return df

def a1(df):
    idx,_ = pd.factorize(df.col)
    df['col'] = idx
    return df

def b(df):
    df['col'] = np.unique(df['col'],return_inverse=True)[1]
    return df

def b1(df):
    _,idx = np.unique(df['col'],return_inverse=True)
    df['col'] = idx    
    return df

print (a(df1))    
print (a1(df2))   
print (b(df3))   
print (b1(df4))
```

Comment: If I had known pandas more, I would have appreciated it more maybe, but this works too! Maybe do something like `idx,_ = pd.factorize(df.col)` and maybe that could be a bit faster? Again, it's a gut-feeling :)

Comment: I hope I once starts to learn `numpy` - there is a lot nice function and it is faster. Thank you. Yes, exactly, I am going to make some tests.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, in large `df` `pandas` is faster as `numpy`.

Comment: Yeah, I must admit I wasn't expecting that! :) But, maybe pandas has really improved it. Time for me to learn pandas huh!! :D

Comment: np.unique sorts; pd.factorize doesn't and guarantees to return uniques in order of appearance

Comment: @Jeff - Thank you, so factorize is better in this question?

Comment: even better is to use a Categorical this is exactly what they do

Comment: Many thanks for the great responses - I think I'll try all of the suggestions on a couple of big data set and report back on any interesting timing issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)'s optional argument `return_inverse` to ID each string based on their uniqueness among others and set those in the input dataframe, like so -

```
_,idx = np.unique(df['col'],return_inverse=True)
df['col'] = idx
```

Please note that the `IDs` correspond to a unique alphabetically sorted array of the strings. If you have to get that unique array, you can replace `_` with it, like so -

```
uniq_lab,idx = np.unique(df['col'],return_inverse=True)
```

Sample run -

```
>>> d = {'col': ["baked","beans","baked","baked","beans"]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
     col
0  baked
1  beans
2  baked
3  baked
4  beans
>>> _,idx = np.unique(df['col'],return_inverse=True)
>>> df['col'] = idx
>>> df
   col
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    1
```

Comment: @jezrael Well I am just hoping `categorical variables` won't have those `Nones` or `NaNs` :)

Comment: Yes, but in real data is it possible. :) Btw, maybe nicer is `df['col'] = np.unique(df['col'],return_inverse=True)[1]`

Comment: @jezrael Well ` 
`df['col'] = np.unique(df['col'],return_inverse=True)` would calculate both the unique labels and the IDs and then select the second element with `[1]`, which I think might take a bit of performance hit. So, with `_,idx`, I think it won't bother itself to calculate the unique labels and that might be a bit faster. There's a bit of gut-feeling in it though :)