# How to encode categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace, categories

Hi I'm new to python and pandas.

I have extracted the unique values of one of the column using pandas.
Now after getting the unique values of the column, which are string.

```
['Others, Senior Management-Finance, Senior Management-Sales'
  'Consulting, Strategic planning, Senior Management-Finance'
  'Client Servicing, Quality Control - Product/ Process, Strategic       
   planning'
  'Administration/ Facilities, Business Analytics, Client Servicing'
  'Sales & Marketing, Sales/ Business Development/ Account Management,    
  Sales Support']
```

I want to replace the string values with the unique integer value.

for simplicity I can give you the dummy input and output.

Input:

```
Col1
  A
  A
  B
  B
  B
  C
  C
```

Unique df value will come as below

```
[ 'A' 'B' 'C' ]
```

after replacing the column should look like this

```
Col1
  1
  1
  2
  2
  2
  3
  3
```

Please suggest me the way how can I do it by using loop or any other way because I have more than `300` unique values.

Comment: Duplicate of [Convert categorical data in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011359/convert-categorical-data-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`pd.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Col1'] = pd.factorize(df.Col1)[0] + 1
print (df)
   Col1
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     3
```

[Factorizing values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#factorizing-values)

Another [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) solution, but slower in huge [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37672792/2901002):

```
_,idx = np.unique(df['Col1'],return_inverse=True) 
df['Col1'] = idx + 1
print (df)
   Col1
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     3
```

Last you can convert values to [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical) - mainly because less [memory usage](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#memory-usage):

```
df['Col1'] = pd.factorize(df.Col1)[0]
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].astype("category")
print (df)
  Col1
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2

print (df.dtypes)
Col1    category
dtype: object
```

Comment: i wonder if there is way to do this for the whole dataframe and not just on 1 column