# Pandas: convert categories to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, series, categorical-data, binning

Suppose I have a dataframe with countries that goes as:

```
cc | temp
US | 37.0
CA | 12.0
US | 35.0
AU | 20.0
```

I know that there is a pd.get_dummies function to convert the countries to 'one-hot encodings'. However, I wish to convert them to indices instead such that I will get `cc_index = [1,2,1,3]` instead.

I'm assuming that there is a faster way than using the get_dummies along with a numpy where clause as shown below:

`[np.where(x) for x in df.cc.get_dummies().values]`

This is somewhat easier to do in R using 'factors' so I'm hoping pandas has something similar.

Comment: Do you mean `cc_index = [0,1,0,2]`?

Comment: sure, forgot about the python 0 index

Comment: Categorical Series or columns in a DataFrame may help.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to encode categorical values in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38025341/7758804)

Comment: The duplicate dates further back [Convert categorical data in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011359/convert-categorical-data-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

First, change the type of the column:

```
df.cc = pd.Categorical(df.cc)
```

Now the data look similar but are stored categorically.  To capture the category codes:

```
df['code'] = df.cc.codes
```

Now you have:

```
   cc  temp  code
0  US  37.0     2
1  CA  12.0     1
2  US  35.0     2
3  AU  20.0     0
```

If you don't want to modify your DataFrame but simply get the codes:

```
df.cc.astype('category').codes
```

Or use the categorical column as an index:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.temp)
df2.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.cc)
```

Comment: The call `df.cc.cat.codes` seems to have changed to just `df.cc.codes`?

Comment: Note that if you have missing values they will be encoded to -1. If you want to avoid treating this case you can cast to string first: df.cc.astype('str').astype('category').cat.codes

Comment: It seems transform `NaN` as `-1`?

Comment: @John How does it work in production or testing phase?

Comment: Could have been helpful if you also add the reverse way, cc to category.

Answer (score 52):

If you wish only to transform your series into integer identifiers, you can use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html).

Note this solution, unlike `pd.Categorical`, will not sort alphabetically. So the first country will be assigned `0`. If you wish to start from `1`, you can add a constant:

```
df['code'] = pd.factorize(df['cc'])[0] + 1

print(df)

   cc  temp  code
0  US  37.0     1
1  CA  12.0     2
2  US  35.0     1
3  AU  20.0     3
```

If you wish to sort alphabetically, specify `sort=True`:

```
df['code'] = pd.factorize(df['cc'], sort=True)[0] + 1
```

Comment: does this take into account NULL values?

Comment: Then, what should we use, pd.factorize(), astype('category') or pd.Categorical()?

Answer (score 33):

If you are using the [`sklearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) library you can use [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). Like `pd.Categorical`, input strings are sorted alphabetically before encoding.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

LE = LabelEncoder()
df['code'] = LE.fit_transform(df['cc'])

print(df)

   cc  temp  code
0  US  37.0     2
1  CA  12.0     1
2  US  35.0     2
3  AU  20.0     0
```

Answer (score 13):

One-line code:

```
df[['cc']] = df[['cc']].apply(lambda col:pd.Categorical(col).codes)
```

This works also if you have a `list_of_columns`:

```
df[list_of_columns] = df[list_of_columns].apply(lambda col:pd.Categorical(col).codes)
```

Furthermore, if you want to keep your `NaN` values you can apply a replace:

```
df[['cc']] = df[['cc']].apply(lambda col:pd.Categorical(col).codes).replace(-1,np.nan)
```

Comment: Is it better to use pd.factorize() or  pd.Categorical()?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, convert to number based on frequency (high frequency - high number):

```
labels = df[col].value_counts(ascending=True).index.tolist()
codes = range(1,len(labels)+1)
df[col].replace(labels,codes,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Will change any columns into Numbers. It will not create a new column but just replace the values with numerical data.

```
def characters_to_numb(*args):
    for arg in args:
        df[arg] = pd.Categorical(df[arg])
        df[arg] = df[arg].cat.codes
    return df
```