# How to convert categorical data to numerical data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have feature => `city` which is categorical data i.e string but instead of hardcoding using `replace()` is there any smart approach ?

```
train['city'].unique()
Output: ['city_149', 'city_83', 'city_16', 'city_64', 'city_100', 'city_21',
       'city_114', 'city_103', 'city_97', 'city_160', 'city_65',
       'city_90', 'city_75', 'city_136', 'city_159', 'city_67', 'city_28',
       'city_10', 'city_73', 'city_76', 'city_104', 'city_27', 'city_30',
       'city_61', 'city_99', 'city_41', 'city_142', 'city_9', 'city_116',
       'city_128', 'city_74', 'city_69', 'city_1', 'city_176', 'city_40',
       'city_123', 'city_152', 'city_165', 'city_89', 'city_36', .......]
```

What I was trying :

```
train.replace(['city_149', 'city_83', 'city_16', 'city_64', 'city_100', 'city_21',
           'city_114', 'city_103', 'city_97', 'city_160', 'city_65',
           'city_90', 'city_75', 'city_136', 'city_159', 'city_67', 'city_28',
           'city_10', 'city_73', 'city_76', 'city_104', 'city_27', 'city_30',
           'city_61', 'city_99', 'city_41', 'city_142', 'city_9', 'city_116',
           'city_128', 'city_74', 'city_69', 'city_1', 'city_176', 'city_40',
           'city_123', 'city_152', 'city_165', 'city_89', 'city_36', .......], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....], inplace=True)
```

Is there any better way to convert the data into numerical ? Because the number of unique values are `123`.
So I need to hard code numbers from 1,2,3,4,...123 to convert it. Suggest some better way to convert it into numerical value.

Comment: @SuperStew I am newbie in python and pandas can you please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088652/pandas-convert-categories-to-numbers try search before post , this is common question

Comment: Could have used: `train['city'].str.split('_').str[1].astype(int)` too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [`pd.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
train['city'] = pd.factorize(train.city)[0]
```

Or [`categorical` dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
train['city'] = train['city'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

**For example:**

```
>>> train
       city
0  city_151
1  city_149
2  city_151
3  city_149
4  city_149
5  city_149
6  city_151
7  city_151
8  city_150
9  city_151
```

`factorize`:

```
train['city'] = pd.factorize(train.city)[0]

>>> train
   city
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     2
9     0
```

Or `astype('category')`:

```
train['city'] = train['city'].astype('category').cat.codes

>>> train
   city
0     2
1     0
2     2
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     2
7     2
8     1
9     2
```

Comment: Best answer thanks :) I am new to pandas and there are hell lot of functions and I was not aware about factorize. Thanks once again.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: @Prune Yes I will accept the answer. I can accept only after 15min time period.

Comment: @sacul Can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342146/i-am-getting-type-error-in-seaborn

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this via `mapping`:

```
   value_mapper = dict(zip(train['city'].unique(), np.arange(1, 124)))
    train['city'].map(value_mapper)
```

Or the more idiomatic `categorical data`:

```
pd.Categorical(train['city']).codes
```

Answer (score 1):

If your values always have an underscore before the integer, a list comprehension might work for you:

```
data = [int(x.split('_')[-1]) for x in train['city']]
```

The comprehension loops across each `x` in `train['city']`, splits `x` into underscore delimited parts, and converts the last part to an integer. This works if you have more than one underscore, like foo_bar_5.