# matplotlip legend base dataframe column

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to create scatter plot base dataframe with 3 columns: 'a', 'b' , 'c'.

```
  a  |  b  |  c
  2  | 0.8 |  k
  3  | 0.4 |  l
  4  | 0.2 |  k
```

I set the 'a' column to x axis and the 'b' column to y axis.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
ax.scatter(df['a'],df['b'])
plt.show()
```

The 'c' column is categorical column. I try to use this column to legend that every category will be in other color.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I don't know the labels in the 'c' column and how much labels.

Comment: Please include a minimal example of the DataFrame ([mre]). You want each point to have a color based on its category?

Comment: @wwii, yes I am.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plot different color for different categorical levels using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139423/plot-different-color-for-different-categorical-levels-using-matplotlib)

Comment: Also - [Scatter plots in Pandas/Pyplot: How to plot by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category) uses `.plot` instead of `.scatter`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are open to other package, try seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='a',y='b', hue='c')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter `c` in `scatter`, like this:

`ax.scatter(df['a'],df['b'],c=df['c'])`

Here is the documentation for `scatter`:

- https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

According to this answer to another question [How to convert categorical data to numerical data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311831/how-to-convert-categorical-data-to-numerical-data), you can use `pd.factorize` to create a column of `int` for each of your categories like so: `df['new_column'] = pd.factorize(df['some_column'])[0]`

Comment: I tried but I get an error: ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers