# Updating values in a particular column of a database using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a col called `id` in a dataframe called _newdata which looks like this. Note that this is a part of the values in the column and not the entire thing.

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
8
8
8
8
10
10
10
```

What I want to do is the make rename the 'id' with values so that it is in running numbers. Which means I want it to look like this

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
```

I tried using this but it didn't seem to do anything to the file. Could someone tell me where I went wrong or suggest a method to do what I want it to do?

```
count = 1 #values start at 1
    for i, row in _newdata.iterrows():
        if row['id']==count or row['id']==count+1:
            pass

        else:
            count+=1
            row['id']=count
```

Comment: Would `pd.factorize(df['id'])[0] + 1` work for your use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: convert categories to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088652/pandas-convert-categories-to-numbers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: convert categories to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088652/pandas-convert-categories-to-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *dense* [rank()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['id'] = df['id'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```