# Get first column value in Pandas DataFrame where row matches condition

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, optimization

Say I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   color  number
0    red       3
1   blue       4
2  green       2
3   blue       2
```

I want to get the first value from the number column where the color column has the value `'blue'` which in this case would return `4`.

I know this can be done using `loc` in something like this:

```
df[df['color'] == 'blue']['number'][0]
```

I'm wondering if there is any more optimal approach given that I only ever need the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `idxmax`

```
df.loc[(df['color'] == 'blue').idxmax(),'number']
Out[698]: 4
```

Comment: You need an if statement here before calling idxmax.

Comment: @coldspeed Like this? `df.loc[if (df['color'] == 'blue').idxmax(),'number']`

Comment: @UBears No, for example see my answer below. Alternatively, `if (df['color'] == 'blue').any(): ...`

Comment: @coldspeed So I need an if statement only to check if the column is empty?

Comment: @UBears no, it's to check whether "blue" exists. Otherwise, if blue does not exist, `idxmax` always returns 0, when the result returned should be empty. Does that make sense? Once again, you can see my answer for example and comparison of the answers

Answer (score 3):

Use `head`—this will return the first row if the color exists, and an empty `Series` otherwise.

```
col = 'blue'
df.query('color == @col').head(1).loc[:, 'number']

1    4
Name: number, dtype: int64
```

Alternatively, to get a single item, use `obj.is_empty`:

```
u = df.query('color == @col').head(1)
if not u.is_empty:
    print(u.at[u.index[0], 'number'])

# 4
```

---

Difference between `head` and `idxmax` for invalid color:

```
df.query('color == "blabla"').head(1).loc[:, 'number']
# Series([], Name: number, dtype: int64)

df.loc[(df['color'] == 'blabla').idxmax(),'number']
# 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`np.where`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
idx = next(iter(df['number'].iloc[np.where(df['color'].eq('blue'))]), -1)  # 4
```

Note this also handles the case where the colour does not exist. In comparison, `df['color'].eq('orange').idxmax()` gives `0` even though `'orange'` does not exist in the series. The above logic will give `-1`.

#### `numba`

> I'm wondering if there is any more optimal approach given that I only
>   ever need the first occurrence.

Yes! For a more efficient solution, see [Efficiently return the index of the first value satisfying condition in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764/efficiently-return-the-index-of-the-first-value-satisfying-condition-in-array). Numba allows you to iterate row-wise efficiently. In this case, you will need to [factorize your strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38088652/9209546) first so that you feed numeric arrays only to Numba:

```
from numba import njit

# factorize series, pd.factorize maintains order,
# i.e. first item in values gives 0 index
idx, values = pd.factorize(df['color'])
idx_search = np.where(values == 'blue')[0][0]

@njit
def get_first_index_nb(A, k):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] == k:
            return i
    return -1

res = df['number'].iat[get_first_index_nb(idx, 1)]  # 4
```

Of course, for a one-off calculation, this is inefficient. But for successive calculations, the solution will likely be a factor faster than solutions which check for equality across the entire series / array.