# Getting error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'video'" when trying to convert categorical values to nominal values

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining

I have a Dataframe and I want to change `'video'` and `'photo'` as objects to 1 and 2 as int's.
I use the following code but get error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'video'
```

Can you help me?

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')    
df[['status_type']] = df[['status_type']].astype('int')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: convert categories to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088652/pandas-convert-categories-to-numbers)

Comment: You can use map, ``df.status_type.map({"video":1, "photo": 2}).astype(int)``

Comment: you can use `pd.factorize()` to  change categories in to numbers [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)

Comment: pd.factorize() worked, Many thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
pd.factorize()
```

to change categories in to numbers.