# Convert identical strings in pandas dataframe to corresponding numbers

Tags: python, pandas

So if I have a column of a pandas dataframe that looks like this :

x

FWD

MID

DEF

GK

MID

Is there anyway I can convert these strings to numbers with identical values taking the same number like this :

x

0

1

2

3

1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: convert categories to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088652/pandas-convert-categories-to-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You can `rank` your column (assuming `df` is your input data frame)

```py
df["x"] = df["x"].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

Ref. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html