# Is there simple way to transfer string values from one colomn to numerical values in another colomn?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and have task to solve. I got large a .csv file and I was wondering is there simple way to transfer string values from one column to numerical values in another colomn.

For example, in one column I have a bunch of different factory names and in the new colum should be numerical value for every factory:

| Factories | NumValues |
| --- | --- |
| FactoryA | 1 |
| FactoryB | 2 |
| FactoryA | 1 |
| FactoryC | 3 |

I know that i could do this with dictionaries, but since there is quite a lot of different names(factories) i was wondering if there is already some library to make this process easier and faster?
I hope I explained my problem well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088652/pandas-convert-categories-to-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **[ngroup()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html)** . Basically, group by factories and give an id for every factory. Does this give the output you want?

```
df['NumValues']=df.groupby('Factories').ngroup() + 1
```