# How to find sum of count, grouped by the id?

Tags: pandas

I would like to get the output for the following problem.
I have the following datatype:

```
id      start        end       count     Time      Train
001     Paris      London        01      05:00      Yes
001     Paris      London        01      05:00      Yes
002     Prague     Vienna        15      15:00      No
003     Frankfurt  London        01      17:00      Yes
015     Paris      London        08      21:00      No
019     Barcelona  Vienna        15      15:00      No
003     Frankfurt  London        01      07:00      Yes
002     Prague     Vienna        15      05:00      No
```

I would like to find the sum of count, grouped by the id. Also ignore the rows that has the same id, start and end . Also I have a data of 4 gb and I would like to find the start and end city of top 5 count. Thank you.

I could like to get output that gives data something similar to this,

```
 Prague -> Vienna     Count : 15
 Barcelona -> Vienna  count : 15
 Paris --> london     Count : 09
 Frankfurt -> London  Count:  02
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating `sum`:

```
df['count'] = df['count'].astype(int)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['id','start','end'])
print (df)
    id      start     end  count   Time Train
0  001      Paris  London      1  05:00   Yes
2  002     Prague  Vienna     15  15:00    No
3  003  Frankfurt  London      1  07:00   Yes
4  015      Paris  London      8  21:00    No
5  019  Barcelona  Vienna     15  15:00    No
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['count'].sum()
print (df1)
    id  count
0  001      1
1  002     15
2  003      1
3  015      8
4  019     15

df11 = df.groupby(['id', 'start', 'end'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
print (df11)
    id      start     end  count
0  001      Paris  London      1
1  002     Prague  Vienna     15
2  003  Frankfurt  London      1
3  015      Paris  London      8
4  019  Barcelona  Vienna     15

df12 = df.groupby(['start', 'end'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
print (df12)
       start     end  count
0  Barcelona  Vienna     15
1  Frankfurt  London      1
2      Paris  London      9
3     Prague  Vienna     15
```

For top values use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
df2 = df.nlargest(5, 'count')[['start','end']]
print (df2)
       start     end
2     Prague  Vienna
5  Barcelona  Vienna
4      Paris  London
0      Paris  London
3  Frankfurt  London
```

Comment: Thank you ! is it possible to get the output ranked based on the start and the end ?

Comment: I am not sure if understand, do you need facorize? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38025451/2901002)

Comment: id 001 and 015 have similar start and end, so i would like to have sum of their count !

Comment: Please check edited answer - do you think groupby by 3 columns `id`, `start` and `end` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT T.* FROM
(
    SELECT *,COUNT(id) AS count FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY id,start,end
) T 
GROUP BY id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0,5
```